# How to fetch uncommon records from two tables in mySQL without primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables, both have same number of columns with none of them having any primary key as below:

Table A

| Name | Ranking | Genre | Category | Rated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M1 | 1 | Comedy | Movie | G |
| M2 | 2 | Action | Series | PG |

Table B

| Name | Ranking | Genre | Category | Rated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MX1 | 44 | Thriller | Series | G |
| M2 | 2 | Action | Series | PG |

I need to fetch the uncommon records from both the tables, where Ranking and Name combined is unique for them.

I have tried using left and right join but it gives me all the records from either one table. My priority here is to fetch just the uncommon records as below:

| Name | Ranking | Genre | Category | Rated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M1 | 1 | Comedy | Movie | G |
| MX1 | 44 | Thriller | Series | G |

Comment: can name or ranking be null?

Comment: yes, all the fields can be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can union two outer joins. For example:

```
select a.*
from a
left join b on a.name = b.name and a.ranking = b.ranking
where b.name is null
union all
select b.*
from b
left join a on a.name = b.name and a.ranking = b.ranking
where a.name is null
```

Comment: since name and ranking can be null, this should use `<=>` instead of `=`

Comment: @ysth I would agree but the question points towards both columns are not null where it says "...where Ranking and Name combined is unique". But... putting logic nuances apart, I always forget this operator that is a shorthand for the standard `IS DISTINCT FROM`.

Comment: Is that standard?  quickly trying it out, that seems to be a postgresql thing; I couldn't get it to work on sql server, sqlite, oracle, or mysql

Comment: normally when joining, people don't expect null to match; here, where the goal is to filter duplicates, not actually join, it's something to consider (and they did confirm in a comment that nulls may exist)

Comment: Then, according to the comments, yes you are right. For the sake of accuracy `IS DISTINCT FROM` was defined in SQL:1999, section 8.13 "distinct predicate".

Answer (score 0):

Try with inner join

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a
INNER JOIN table_b ON table_a.name = table_b.name AND table_a.ranking = table_b.ranking;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).